# Get a List plot with help of module

Tags: plotting

I just want to get a list plot for my model which I wrote with help of the module.

```
pp[nn_] := Module[{},
  n = nn;
(*......Main code Here ....*)
ff[Solve::"svars"];
 N[U /. qsol];
 ListPlot[N[U /. qsol], n, AxesLabel -> {"n", "E (J)"}]]
Off[Solve::"svars"];
Show[Table[pp[j], {j, 1, 5}]]
```

It gave me the correct answer, but I couldn't get any action.

Its the answer :

```
Show[{ListPlot[0., 1, AxesLabel -> {"n", "E (J)"}], 
  ListPlot[3087.46, 2, AxesLabel -> {"n", "E (J)"}], 
  ListPlot[7312.15, 3, AxesLabel -> {"n", "E (J)"}], 
  ListPlot[8717.81, 4, AxesLabel -> {"n", "E (J)"}], 
  ListPlot[9210.08, 5, AxesLabel -> {"n", "E (J)"}]}]
```

I want to get a plot that evaluates all my code for n and plots it for every n.

Update: I think I have to create a List that saved my results in a list for each n, after that, I can plot it. I tried to use append but it didn't work.

Comment: The arguments of `ListPlot` in you code are not lists and that's why no plos are generated. You should output the data of your module and then use `ListPlot` on it.

Comment: `ListPlot[{0., 3087.46, 7312.15, 8717.81, 9210.08}, AxesLabel -> {"n", "E (J)"}]`

Comment: @N0va Is there any way like other programming tools that I say first save the result of my `N[U /. qsol]` for its n in a list, after that plot it?

Comment: @BobHanlon It was an example I want that my module loop does it for each n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is like that :

```
ff[Solve::"svars"];
 N[U /. qsol]
 ]
```

and in another cell

```
UvaluesAgainstApproximationDegree = Table[pp[j], {j, 2, 15}]

ListPlot[UvaluesAgainstApproximationDegree, AxesLabel -> {"n", "U"}]
```

[image]